# How to see the value of a top level empty getter without running the code in Swift?

Tags: swift, posix, getter, darwin

`public var O_RDONLY: Int32 { get }`

When I'm looking at stuff inside `Darwin.sys.*` or `Darwin.POSIX.*` for example, a lot of these constants are defined as getters. But how does one see the actual value without evaluating the code?

Comment: The fact that a property as defined as `{ get }` does not mean in any way that it's value is a build-time constant, it can very easily be a computed property, so you cannot know it's value without actually running the code.

Comment: These are imported from C header files (such as `#define O_RDONLY  0x0000` in sys/fcntl.h). Unfortunately, the generated Swift interface does not show the actual value, although it is known at compile time.

Comment: @DávidPásztor: In this case it *is* a build-time constant, and Xcode *could* show the actual value in the help panel if the importer would be more intelligent.

Comment: What I sometimes do (as a poor workaround): Add some C file to the project, use `O_RDONLY` in some dummy C code, and “jump to definition” from there.

Comment: @MartinR Ah, I see. So they are generated by XCode when one jumps to "definition". But then why wouldn't they just generate it like `public let O_RDONLY: Int32 = 0`? It doesn't matter anyway ‍♂️

Comment: *“Why wouldn't the just ...”* is something which you have to ask Apple.  Actually  I don't know if the importer is part of the Swift project (which is open source) or of Xcode (which is closed source). In the first case you may get some feedback at https://forums.swift.org. In the second case all you can do is to file a feedback report.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, my response wasn't an actual question, more of an exclamation and an aknowledgement of what you said before :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public var O_RDONLY: Int32 { get }
```

is what the Swift importer generates from the macro definition

```
#define O_RDONLY        0x0000          /* open for reading only */
```

in the `<sys/fcntl.h>` include file. Although this is a fixed value, known at compile time, the Swift importer does not show the value in the generated Swift interface.

Note also that a macro definition in a C header file may depend on other macros, and on other “variables” such as compiler flags, the processor architecture, etc.

I am not aware of a way to navigate to that C definition from a Swift file, or any other way to show the defined value in a pure Swift project. As a workaround, one can

- add a C file to the project,
- use the macro in some C function, and
- “jump to definition” from there.

Comment: Thanks! Please see a solution I posted in my question. It's not bulletproof, but one only needs to add an import, if it does work for their use cases.

Comment: @Vitaly: If that is a solution (I could not try it yet) the you should post it as an *answer.*

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following solution:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { exec } = require("child_process");

const getterRegEx = /^(.*)public var (.+): (.+) { get }(.*)$/;

const code = String(fs.readFileSync('./generatedSwift.swift'));

const lines = code.split('\n').map((line, i) => {
  const arr = getterRegEx.exec(line);
  if (arr) {
    const [all, prefix, constant, type, suffix] = arr;
    return `print("let ${constant}: ${type} = ", ${constant}, separator: "")`;
  }
  return `print("""\n${line}\n""")`;
});
lines.unshift('import Foundation');

fs.writeFileSync('./regeneratedSwift.swift', lines.join('\n'));

exec('swift ./regeneratedSwift.swift', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${err}`);
    return;
  }
  if (stderr) {
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

Copy definitions generated by the XCode and save into a file named `generatedSwift.swift` the run `node index.js` in the same folder.

The output will contain the Swift code where all
`public var Constant: Type { get }`
are replaced with
`let Constant = Value`
and all other lines will remain the same.